# ios pushViewController loop memory cash

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory, pushviewcontroller

I have problem "How to handle view stack" if I have 2 viewController which can push to themself

```
#sample
A,B

A can push to B and
B can push to A
```

I found this problem when user try to push

```
A -> B -> A -> B ...
```

It crashes!

so I tried to use delegate to pop and reload itself, it realy good but It not work when I have a lot of viewController like this

A -> B -> C -> D -> A -> B -> C -> D ...

or unpredictable push

A -> B -> C -> A -> D -> B -> C -> A -> D ...

I think it out of memory
so how should I do?

Comment: you should post the relevant parts of your source code and more info on the crash itself (eg. crash log, exception)

Comment: I suggest to reconsider your app navigation, that many push/pop can be cumbersome for the user.

Comment: If you want to be able to go directly from any view controller to any other, then you should use a tab bar controller, or a custom container controller that behaves like a tab bar controller (but doesn't have a tab bar).

Comment: Are you creating new instances each time you try to push a controller? If no, than that's may be the issue - probably you just can't push a controller already pushed and existing on the stack.

Comment: @krafter I creating new instances everytime i pushed.

Comment: I saw this behavior in other app such as instargram 
but I pushed 40-50 pageController but they didn't cashed like my app